# Cypress: Typing input element value (text) to log

Tags: cypress

I've got an input field whose text contents I need to verify. Now, verifying it works fine. Bug for some reason, I cannot for the life of me manage to type the value to cy.log(). I've done it before, but I'm unable to find the example. And I've been trying all variants of invoke('val'), 'value' and 'text', to no avail.

```
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=byggrad]').eq(0)
      .within(() => {
        cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=adresserad]').eq(0)
          .within(() => {
            cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=etasjerad]').eq(0)
              .within(() => {
                cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=finansieringsobjektrad]').eq(boligrad)
                  .within(() => {
                    cy.get('input[data-e2e-selector=boligbetegnelse]').should('have.value', '123');
                    cy.log('BOLIGBETEGNELSE: ' + cy.get('input[data-e2e-selector=boligbetegnelse]').invoke('val'));
                    //cy.log('BOLIGBETEGNELSE: ' + cy.get('input[data-e2e-selector=boligbetegnelse]').invoke('value'));                    
                    //cy.log('BOLIGBETEGNELSE: ' + cy.get('input[data-e2e-selector=boligbetegnelse]').invoke('text'));
                  });
              });
          });
      });
```

Here's the cypress output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The complete markup:

```
<input _ngcontent-pxm-c10="" class="hb-inputfelt hb-inputfelt--10tegn ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-e2e-selector="boligbetegnelse" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" id="finansieringsobjekt-boligbetegnelse-319-H02-0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since value it's an attribute of an input element.

You can find all properties for element: devtools -> find element in DOM -> right hand side find tab properties -> scroll down and find value property

```
  cy.get("input[data-e2e-selector=boligbetegnelse]").invoke('prop','value').then((value) => {
    cy.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain off of the .invoke() call to get the value.

e.g.:

```
cy.get("matcher").invoke("val").then((value) => {
    cy.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Same result. "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.invoke() errored because the property: value does not exist on your subject." Cypress claims that value as a property doesn't exist on the object, so no matter of chaining will change that I think.

Comment: The "value" one doesn't exist, but "val" or "text" should, according to your screenshots.